# java Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int

Tags: java

```
   long A[]=new long[1000];
   Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
   for(long I=0;I<A.length;I++)
   {
    A[I]=a.nextLong();//error
   }
   return true;
}
```

Here why I am getting type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int

I am not understanding why we get type Mismatch as I is long and A[] is also long
then why we are getting type mismatch long to int.

Comment: Why? Explicitly given in the Java Language Specification [10.4. Array Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-10.html): "Arrays must be indexed by int values; short, byte, or char values may also be used as index values because they are subjected to unary numeric promotion (§5.6) and become int values.

An attempt to access an array component with a long index value results in a compile-time error."

Answer (score 3):

Use an int instead of a long in a for loop:

```
long A[]=new long[1000];
    Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int I=0;I<A.length;I++)
    {
        A[I]=a.nextLong();//error
    }
```

You can't index an array with a long type: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4